# Display all locations with random locations method

Tags: php, mysql, geolocation, coordinates

I'm facing a problem to display the random locations around the location are fetching from mysql, the method found [Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25877/generating-random-locations-nearby). and its working prefect when i give value for lat and lng directly ,but in my code after using mysql data not able to display the random location on map ,google map displaying only the location from mysql as shown in the picture. so i wish someone can help me about my problem.

[the result after run the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihjpg.png)

the database and data define as:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `map` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `desc` text NOT NULL,
  `lat` text NOT NULL,
  `lon` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `map`
--

INSERT INTO `poi_example` (`id`, `name`, `desc`, `lat`, `lon`) VALUES
(1, '100 Club', 'Oxford Street, London  W1&lt;br/&gt;3 Nov 2010 : Buster Shuffle&lt;br/&gt;', '51.514980', '-0.144328'),
(2, '93 Feet East', '150 Brick Lane, London  E1 6RU&lt;br/&gt;7 Dec 2010 : Jenny &amp; Johnny&lt;br/&gt;', '51.521710', '-0.071737'),
(3, 'Adelphi Theatre', 'The Strand, London  WC2E 7NA&lt;br/&gt;11 Oct 2010 : Love Never Dies', '51.511010', '-0.120140'),
(4, 'Albany, The', '240 Gt. Portland Street, London  W1W 5QU', '51.521620', '-0.143394'),
(5, 'Aldwych Theatre', 'Aldwych, London  WC2B 4DF&lt;br/&gt;11 Oct 2010 : Dirty Dancing', '51.513170', '-0.117503'),
(6, 'Alexandra Palace', 'Wood Green, London  N22&lt;br/&gt;30 Oct 2010 : Lynx All-Nighter', '51.596490', '-0.109514');
```

and the php file for displaying the map:

```
    <?php
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "hani", "hani") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("map4") or die(mysql_error());
    ?>

<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "hani", "hani") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("map4") or die(mysql_error());
?>

    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>Google Maps</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body { font: normal 10pt Helvetica, Arial; }
            #map { width: 1300px; height: 600px; border: 0px; padding: 0px; }
        </style>
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=key=loadMap&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //Sample code written by August Li
            var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png",
                       new google.maps.Size(320, 320), new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                       new google.maps.Point(16, 32));
            var center = null;
            var map = null;
            var currentPopup;
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            function addMarker(lat, lng, info) {
                var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                bounds.extend(pt);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: pt,
                    icon: icon,
                    map: map
                });
                var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: info,
                    maxWidth: 300
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                    if (currentPopup != null) {
                        currentPopup.close();
                        currentPopup = null;
                    }
                    popup.open(map, marker);
                    currentPopup = popup;
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function() {
                    map.panTo(center);
                    currentPopup = null;
                });

            } 
            // random location method start from there 


                // random location method end there 

            function initMap() {
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
                    zoom: 14,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    mapTypeControl: true,
                    mapTypeControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
                    },
                    navigationControl: true,
                    navigationControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.ZOOM_PAN
                    }
                });
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM map")or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
  $name = $row['name'];
  $lat = $row['lat'];
  $lon = $row['lon'];
  $desc = $row['desc'];



  echo("addMarker($lat, $lon, '<b>$name</b><br />$desc');\n");

}

?>
 center = bounds.getCenter();
     map.fitBounds(bounds);

     }
     </script>
     </head>
     <body onload="initMap()" style="margin:0px; border:0px; padding:0px;">
     <div id="map"></div>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I use mysql\_\* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: there is no duplicate sir, i'm using php 5.6 and the code working good with code Mysql and mysqli, you can check the picture for the output. the problem is the random location no displaying on the map

Comment: You need to stop using PHP 5 as soon as possible. It is no longer supported and you are less likely to get any help for PHP versions which the community does no longer use.

Comment: i will update the code to php 7 and using mysqli.

Comment: Try PDO it is much easier and better. You are missing on so much more by not upgrading yet. PHP 7 has a lot of new features and is generally faster.

Comment: sure sir, will take in your advice , thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has several syntax problems :

- Your function `addMarker` finishes before the part that generates random markers : you have to move the `}` after the calls to googlemaps function just before the `initMap()` function
- `google.maps.Marker1` : remove the trailing 1
- `, x0 = long` : `lng`, not `long`

Comment: thanks sir, i did what you told me and now not display anything or show map, could you plz edit the code . thanks again